# i want to create 2 php variable with javascri[pt value

Tags: javascript, php, variables, location, latitude-longitude

am working on a PHP project as I am beginner so i don't have so much gather knowledge of PHP I want to get user location on load its coming long and lat but in the javascript variable I want that long and lat in PHP variable i don't know how it can be done please help me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="getLocation()">





<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
<?php
echo '<script>alert("Welcome to Geeks for Geeks")</script>';


?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

php work in server side (basically load first to javascript), in that case you can send the data by get so php take it by $_GET.

So you send the page ([www.mypage.com/latitude=xxxxxxxx](http://www.mypage.com/latitude=xxxxxxxx)) and when you need it take it by $_GET["latitude"]

UPDATE

This is ajax implemente at the sale page, the php code at the first line before the doctype

```
<?php
// Handle AJAX request (start)
if( isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST['name']) ){
 echo $_POST['name'];
 exit;
}
// Handle AJAX request (end)
?>
<!-- Script -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var name = latitudevalue
 
  $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   data: {ajax: 1,name: name},
   success: function(response){
    Document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = response ;
   }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: if you want no load the page you can implement ajax, following the same logic of get or post

Comment: could you guys explain little bit more how i can put $_GET["latitude"]

Comment: using what you have now you can reload the page with window.location.replace("mypage.com?latitude=" + position.coords.longitude); (page start a loop so ask first if $_GET["latitude"] exist ) and late x.innerHTML = <?= $_GET["latitude"] ?> or print direct in html code with the same syntax

Comment: Brother thanks for your reply but am still unable to understand how it can be done let me explain to you my PHP code

$userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$LocationArray = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://ip-get-geolocation.com/api/json/'.$userIP), true); 
    $sajid = $LocationArray['lat'];
    $sajid1= $LocationArray['lon'];

in this code, I am getting the user location from his/her IP address but I want to get the actual location from the browser anyhow just I want to put the long and lat values in $sajid and in the $sajid1 variable that's it please help me in this scenario

Comment: I updated my msg witch ajax code so you can implemente it

Comment: brother its showing blank pages not any value are showing there

Comment: Did you change the name of bar to fit with your code?

Comment: And remember call jquery before the script